How can I upload images via TIptap editor from my computer file system without FileHandler extension?
I want to implement wysiwyg editor in my Nuxt 3 project using TipTap. I want to be able to load images from computer file system (I mean, I click image button and the window with my files opens where I can choose image/images I need). But using only image extension in Tiptap doesn't provide scenario of file system upload. FileHandler extension is not for free and in it I don't see any ability to use computer file system either.
What's my solution then? Is there any way to implement this upload scenario in Tiptap or maybe it's better to use another library?
